Scope of 18 USC § 241
Is there a comprehensive list of all the rights that could fall under conspiracy to deprive someone of their rights under 18 USC § 241?

@Jen Your edit seems to completely change the sense of the question, which was originally specific to civil rights, not just 18 USC 241.

18 USC 241 reads:

If two or more persons conspire to injure, oppress, threaten, or intimidate any person in any State, Territory, Commonwealth, Possession, or District in the free exercise or enjoyment of any right or privilege secured to him by the Constitution or laws of the United States, or because of his having so exercised the same; or [...]

What are those rights? Well, you can start with the Constitution and each article that guarantees a right. But you also would need to read all of the USC itself, where it offers specific rights and privileges, such as 17 USC 106, which grants the privilege of copyright, or 35 USC 101, which grants the privilege to apply for patents.
And then there is caselaw, which additionally explains what those guaranteed rights are. For example, the case Obergefell v. Hodges, 576 U.S. 644, did explain that the 14th Amendment to the Constitution enshrines the right to marry for same-sex couples.
As a result of there being so many different sourses, there is no finite list of rights, but a lot of things that are in or close to the penumbra of those rights can be one of those "rights or privileges secured to him by the constitution or laws of the United States".

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
